# How to get device information such as macaddress in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, webapi

How can I get the device's information in ReactJS.
The devices will be connect to the laptop, And I need to get the device's infor such as mac address or id, name.

The connection between device and laptop will be bluetooth or wired.

And I need to use ReactJS to get and show device's infor to the website.

How I can do it?? I try using navigator.usb but I cannot got any device list need to connect

```
const requestDeviceUSB = () => {
navigator.usb
  .requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: 0x05ac }] })
  .then((devices) => {
    console.log("usb devices", devices);
  });
```

};